# What is the correct arrangement of symlinks to allow both openssl 1.1.0 and 1.0.2 shared libraries to co-exist?

Tags: openssl, libraries, dynamic-linking, version, shared-library

I want to have openssl-1.0.2 and openssl-1.1.0 both available for dynamic linking to different applications. I'm slightly unsure about this, because I would expect 1.0.2 to be installed in a file called libssl.so.1.0.2 but it's actually in a file called libssl.so.1.0.0.

This the setup with only 1.0.2 installed:

```
/versions64/local/lib/libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.0.0
/versions64/local/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
```

And this is what it looks like after 1.1.0 is installed:

```
/versions64/local/lib/libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.1
/versions64/local/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
/versions64/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1
```

Are applications that require 1.0.2 going to know to look in libssl.so.1.0.0 and ignore libssl.so?

Comment: Have a look at how Debian is doing that; I have (or had, not sure after the updates), several servers with at least 2 versions of `libssl`

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it. I ran Apache 2.4, which was compiled to use OpenSSL 1.0.2. Apache started successfully and served an SSL site.

First I renamed the new `libssl.so.1.1` library and Apache still restarted successfully. Then I renamed the new `libssl.so` link and Apache still started successfully. Finally I renamed the old `libssl.so.1.0.0` library and Apache FAILED to restart.

This proves it is ignoring the `libssl.so` symlink and correctly using the `libssl.so.1.0.0` that is was compiled against, as expected.